# Bitmap taking too much time to set as Wallpaper

Tags: java, android, bitmap

when I want to set the image as wallpaper it takes more than 5seconds or even more on some occasions causing the app crash.

I have done a lot of searches and found the way to use **setStream** in place of **setBitmap** but actually didn't work as there is no full code mentioned by anyone.
so please help me to set the wallpaper quickly.

My Code:

```
 private void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mNotifyManager.cancel(id);
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        success();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        failure();
    }
}
```

Comment: simply because the size is too much and you're trying to load the whole bitmap on the RAM so you might face an `out of memory` exception, reduce/rescale your bitmap first.

Comment: An easy solution would be using image loading libs such as `Glide` and `Picasso`

Comment: @Mosius already using that.

Answer (score 0):

Resize your bitmap according to screen size 
it will reduce time to set

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,screenWidth, screenHeight, true);
```

Now you can set this bitmap for wallpaper

Comment: seems to be good but what when applied for multiple screen sizes? will it work same for all screen sizes?

Comment: No you can set device width and height dynamic.

Comment: @KunalUkey see my answer check my answer I had updated according to your issue .

Comment: getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);  **getWindowManager()** getting red color i tried adding import but still didn't worked :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use below functions to resize bitmap-

```
fun decodeSampledBitmapFromFilePath(filepath: String, reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Bitmap? {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options)

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight)
        if(options.outHeight == 0 && options.outWidth == 0){
            return null
        }
        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options)
    }

    /**
     * Method to calculate a sample size value that is a power of two based on a target width and height.
     * @param options
     * @param reqWidth
     * @param reqHeight
     * @return sampleSize
     */
    fun calculateInSampleSize(options: BitmapFactory.Options, reqWidth: Int, reqHeight: Int): Int {
        // Raw height and width of image
        val height = options.outHeight
        val width = options.outWidth
        var inSampleSize = 1

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            /* val halfHeight = height / 2
             val halfWidth = width / 2

             // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
             // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
             while (halfHeight / inSampleSize >= reqHeight && halfWidth / inSampleSize >= reqWidth) {
                 inSampleSize *= 2
             }*/
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round(width.toFloat() / reqWidth.toFloat())
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round(height.toFloat() / reqHeight.toFloat())
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize
    }
```